# Owin SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication and existing HTTP Module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, httpmodule

In an existing ASP.NET MVC application I've added WebAPI. I've used most of the template code that's generated from a brand new project.

I'm facing some issues concerning authentication. In order to avoid the normal login procedure for the api I've added:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

as per the default template.

However, I get an error calling my api stating: "No OWIN authentication manager is associated with the request."

I found out that this is caused because there's a custom HTTP module active. Removing the module from the web.config makes the API work. However the 'normal' web application needs this module.

Is there a way to let the HTTP module coexist with the owin authentication?

The Module is defined like this:

```
public class MGPContextInitializerModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.AcquireRequestState += AcquireRequestState;
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
        }
    }

    private void AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
           InitializeUserCulture(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current).GetSessionID());
        }
    }

    private void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeCustomer((HttpApplication)sender);
    }

    private static void InitializeInstantie(HttpApplication application)
    {
        HttpContextBase contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(application.Context);
        RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(contextBase);

        if (routeData != null)
        {
            var customer = routeData.Values["customer"];
            if (customer != null)
            {
                Initializer.InitializeCustomer(customer.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind indicating the module in question? I'm experiencing the same issue and have yet to be able to track down the source.

Comment: Well it's actually a custom module which is causing issues. I have no other modules (add or removes) listed. I've added the source code of the module in the original post. Removing the module from the Web.Config fixes the issues, but I'm searching for a hybrid solution. So having Owin work AND have the module in place. I know I can change it to an ActionFilter, but in a legacy app one tries to avoid unnecessary changes.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I don't think it'll help in my particular instance, but it's good to have for reference.